# crossfilter filter does not apply on update data. Is it by design?

Tags: crossfilter

I am managing a large dateset using crossfilter in my recent project, in which I will need ability to change the data value (a bool). However after the value changed, the filter on this property does not filter out changed item. For instance I have large dataset whose data has a property of Boolean named  as 'Ignore'; I create a dimension for this property to filer out the data have ignore= true. In app, user has a capability to change this value from false to true. after value changed true, clear filters and refilter the data on this dimension, I am still getting the data item which supposed being filterred out. Is it by design or there is way to around it?

Answer (score 0):

From the API Docs and source it appears this behaviour is not supported.

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference